# Applying a function with time elements

Tags: r, apply, lapply, posixct

I have a data frame showing many contracts of a long time frame. I want to do two calculations.

1) calculate how many hours there are for each month of the contract and multiply this with a cost and a quantity
2) and get the data returned in a data frame per group.

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Fromdate = structure(c(1388530800, 1388530800, 
1388530800, 1388530800, 1388530800, 1388530800, 1388530800, 1388530800, 
1388530800, 1420066800, 1388530800, 1388530800, 1388530800, 1388530800, 
1420066800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CET"), 
    Todate = structure(c(1419980400, 1419980400, 1419980400, 
    1419980400, 1419980400, 1419980400, 1419980400, 1419980400, 
    1419980400, 1451516400, 1419980400, 1419980400, 1419980400, 
    1419980400, 1451516400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "CET"), 
    Cost = c(1.58, 1.58, 1.58, 1.58, 1.58, 1.58, 1.58, 1.58, 
    1.58, 1.58, 1.58, 1.58, 1.58, 1.58, 1.58), Quantity = c(0.112311303786473, 
    0.0205773161568493, 0.0493657482020549, 0.0437536029132876, 
    0.0278005475976713, 0.0295483138287671, 0.066499635323105, 
    0.066499635323105, 0.733925139981052, 0.733925139981051, 
    0.1067060088379, 0.436262087700001, 0.0667432627739724, 0.0925740588127852, 
    0.0925740588127855), Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
    "B", "C"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

1) The calculation I want to do, is simply an apply of this:

```
table(
  format(seq.POSIXt(df$Fromdate[1], to = df$Todate[1], by = "hour"), "%Y-%m")
) *  df$Cost[1] * df$Quantity[1]


2014-01  2014-02  2014-03  2014-04  2014-05  2014-06  2014-07  2014-08  2014-09  2014-10  2014-11  2014-12 
132.0242 119.2476 131.8467 127.7653 132.0242 127.7653 132.0242 132.0242 127.7653 132.2016 127.7653 127.9428
```

But, for the life of me, I can't get this into and apply, lapply or any purrr-functions.

2) In the end I also want to group it by the groups, so the end result should be a list or data frame with the individual months and summarized costs per group.

Something like this:

```
df %>% group_by(Group, month_year) %>% 
  summarise_each(table(
    format(
      seq.POSIXt("FromDate", "Todate", by = "hour")
      , "%Y-%m")  # this is month_year
    ) * Cost * Quantity )
```

Or easier to understand - the final result should simply be: (numbers are not correct)

```
  2014-01 2014-02 .... 2015-12
A   600     900     ...  1100
B   650     600     ...  1870
C   400     700     ...  990
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry @NoThanks, but this thing has turned into a rabbit hole that I do not have the time to fully explore, so this will only partially answer your question.

First we split the data in two steps (Step one for the different years, indicated by `df$Fromdate`, step two for `df$Group`):

```
part1 <- split(df, df$Fromdate)
part2 <- lapply(part1, function(x) split(x, x$Group))
```

Now we loop over the innermost list elements, creating the tables for each row, split by years and groups:

```
part3 <- lapply(part2, function(a) lapply(a, function(b) Map(function(w,x,y,z) table(format(seq.POSIXt(w, to = x, by = "hour"), "%Y-%m")
) *  y * z, b$Fromdate, b$Todate, b$Cost, b$Quantity)))
```

Now we `rbind` the groups within years.

```
part4 <- lapply(part3, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) do.call(rbind, y)))
```

Now we need to remove possible `NULL` objects from the nested list. We use a handy little function I once found somewhere on the internet:

```
rmNullObs <- function(x) {
  is.NullOb <- function(x) is.null(x) | all(sapply(x, is.null))
   x <- Filter(Negate(is.NullOb), x)
   lapply(x, function(x) if (is.list(x)) rmNullObs(x) else x)
}

part4 <- rmNullObs(part4)
```

And now we `rbind` the years:

```
part5 <- lapply(part4, function(x) do.call(rbind, lapply(x, function(y) colSums(y))))
```

leaving us with this:

```
> part5
$`2014-01-01`
    2014-01  2014-02   2014-03   2014-04   2014-05   2014-06   2014-07   2014-08   2014-09   2014-10   2014-11   2014-12
A  298.3570 269.4837  297.9560  288.7326  298.3570  288.7326  298.3570  298.3570  288.7326  298.7580  288.7326  289.1336
B 1053.8216 951.8389 1052.4052 1019.8274 1053.8216 1019.8274 1053.8216 1053.8216 1019.8274 1055.2380 1019.8274 1021.2438
C  825.5506 745.6586  824.4409  798.9199  825.5506  798.9199  825.5506  825.5506  798.9199  826.6602  798.9199  800.0295

$`2015-01-01`
   2015-01   2015-02  2015-03  2015-04  2015-05  2015-06  2015-07  2015-08  2015-09  2015-10  2015-11  2015-12
B 862.7437 779.25236 861.5841 834.9132 862.7437 834.9132 862.7437 862.7437 834.9132 863.9033 834.9132 836.0728
C 108.8227  98.29143 108.6764 105.3122 108.8227 105.3122 108.8227 108.8227 105.3122 108.9689 105.3122 105.4585
```

Combining these is tricky due to the lack of common columns and the missing groups. A possible solution I've tried involved manually adding `NA` filled rows for the missing Groups via a `for` loop, but since this heavily depends on your real data, you'd have to figure it out by yourself or just work with these year-by-year comparisons.

Hope it helped.

Comment: looks good, however it seems to be missing the one observation from 2015 ? df[10, ] ?

Comment: Thanks a lot LAP, appreciate the effort!